# Emgu CV Blob Detection

Tags: c#, blob, emgucv

I'm using Emgu CV 2.1 and want to have a simple blob detection. I search for white blobs in a black image. Unfortunalty I can not find out how to do this! Do I need an additional library? Or how is this function called in emgu cv? Or is there really no blob detection in emgu cv?

Thanks for any help
Benks

Answer (score 2):

For starters the basic Hough blob tracking method EMGU forums have an example
[here](http://www.emgu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=225) : (2nd Comment)

http://www.emgu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=225

[Here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.5.0.0/Help/html/04e0b6a7-3d11-eec8-6c22-44e5bf3023b2.htm) is the declaration sytax

http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.5.0.0/Help/html/04e0b6a7-3d11-eec8-6c22-44e5bf3023b2.htm

An alternative which is a c# only contribution from AlbertG can be found [here](http://emgu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=205)

http://emgu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=205

Comment: Most of these links are now broken

Answer (score 2):

You have  SimpleBlobDetector class just for that ,
Just call Detect() on your image.

Another way is to use cannyEdgeDetection() followed with FindContours method, both in Image class .