# Are there libraries like Predator or CMT for C#?

Tags: c#, computer-vision, kinect, emgucv

I have been using Emgu CV for 2 years to provide Facial Recognition to an open source project already using Kinect API. All the **code is in C#**.

Now I'd like to also provide Blob Tracking Learning Detection like [Predator](http://personal.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Personal/Z.Kalal/tld.html) or [CMT](http://www.gnebehay.com/cmt/) and don't know what library to use. I didn't find a Predator implementation in C#. I also didn't find a Blob library build on top of the Kinect SDK.

So should I keep [digging into Emgu CV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174527/emgu-cv-blob-detection)? Or looking for something new? Maybe using Kinect leverage?